# Null reference exception on column click in datagridview

Tags: c#, .net

I have a data grid on my form filled by a dataset.  On the `SelectionChanged` event I have this code:

```
int index = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
```

But when you click the column to sort the data,   a null reference expection gets thrown.

I need to be able to get the current row they have selected and get data out of it.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var index = e.RowIndex;
    }
```

Comment: ah didnt think it would be a different event.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Probably because when you select a column all row selections get removed. So therefore the `CurrentRow` is `null`.

You have to capture the selected item when selection occurs.